# Cobertura coverage report not showing in MR's diff

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, tox

I have recently added the cobertura coverage report to my repository, but it still does not show the coverage in an MR's diff.

Here is the job of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` that generates the coverage report:

```yaml
coverage-report:
  stage: coverage
  script:
    - tox -e coverage-report
  coverage: '/(?i)total.*? (100(?:\.0+)?\%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    name: "coverage"
    paths:
      - public/coverage
    expire_in: 1 week
    reports:
      cobertura: public/coverage/coverage.xml
    expose_as: "coverage"
```

And here is my `tox.ini`:

```ini
[tox]
envlist =
    coverage-report
minversion = 3.4

[testenv:coverage-report]
basepython = python2.7-32
skip_install = True
deps =
  coverage
commands =
  coverage run -m pytest -s -vv -x --junitxml=public/test-report.xml tests/
  coverage report
  coverage html
  coverage xml
```

I am pretty sure everything goes well with the report because not only does its XML exist under `public/coverage` (which I can see through the published artifacts), but the coverage % summary also shows up in the job and MR. But the coverage still does not show up in the MR's diff. I also tried opening the Network tab of my browser and look for the `merge_requests/26/coverage_reports.json` HTTP request, and that is coming up empty (more specifically, the response is `{"files":{}}`), which I do not think is supposed to be happening.

I am using Python 2.7-32 and Coverage.py to get the report. My GitLab is self-hosted with version `14.9.5-ee`. [Here](https://easyupload.io/d6xlfw) is a link to download my `coverage.xml`. It is not the complete coverage, but it shows 2 files which show up in the MR's diff but have no coverage information.

Answer (score 0):

Give [coverage_report](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportscoverage_report) in this form.

```yaml
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - public/coverage
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: public/coverage/coverage.xml
```

Also at times it can take some time for the coverage to be reflected in the diff. Gitlab runs it a background process when it's completed it should show. Sometimes takes a while for me.

Comment: I've waited multiple hours and days. It never shows up. Also, that format of writing it is only for GitLab version > 15. Mine is 14.9.5, so I write it the old way